# How to run .exe in background, created from perl script by using pp module of perl PAR

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module

I am using PAR:Packager to create exe from perl. I wish to make .exe with hidden functionality especially for windows i.e. executing in background for those system where active perl is not installed. how to do this??

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, just note that perl is not built for background operation pretty much of any kind, given the memory and general resource management. Thus I would refrain doing any hardcore processing in the background, because that will be massive a burden on the system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pp -g`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp#-g) will build an executable without a console window.  No windows will be created (unless you make them yourself).

Answer (score 2):

You may check out a similar thread here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/21511/run-perl-script-as-a-windows-service

I've used [srvany.exe](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197) recently and found it useful.